# Multi-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, multidimensional-array

I can't figure out a way to write a PHP script that will print the first name, last name, email and account ID 
of this multidimensional array. This is json data returned from an cURL script. Can you help me my friends?

```
Array
(
    [operationResult] => SUCCESS
    [responseDateTime] => 2013-03-15T15:52:25.180-05:00
    [page] => Array
        (
            [currentPage] => 1
            [pageSize] => 10
            [totalPage] => 1
            [totalResults] => 1
        )
    [searchResults] => Array
        (
            [nameValuePairs] => Array
                (
                    [nameValuePair] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Account Id
                                    [value] => 7601
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => User Email 1
                                    [value] => jim@email.com
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => First Name
                                    [value] => Jim
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Last Name
                                    [value] => Burns
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**Edit**: Sorry to not include my attempts. I have tried the following:

```
foreach ($client_emails_array as $operation) 
{ 
    echo $operation['page']['searchResults']['nameValuePairs']['nameValuePair']['name']."<br>";
    echo $operation['page']['searchResults']['nameValuePairs']['nameValuePair']['value']."<br>";
}
```

This has given me little success

Comment: Sorry, the first part of my array is not formatted correctly, sorry about this.

Comment: we expect that you tried something before asking it on SO. Please add some information about what you tried and why that didn't work to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a strict sense, just printing the values can be done like so:

```
foreach ($operation['searchResults']['nameValuePairs']['nameValuePair'] as $key => $data) {
    echo $data['value'];
}
```

If you want to do more you can add more logic to the `foreach` block for retrieving which value has been printed and so on.

Comment: I tried this and got: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/truthloo/public_html/blerg/z2support.php on line 56 ; is there perhaps something wrong with my array? It is originally json code, but decoded via the json_decode function: $client_emails_array = json_decode($result_2,TRUE);

Comment: Given the array in the question, the code works.  Your actual data is in some way different.  Is this the var_dump from the json_decode?

Answer (score 1):

The data structure is actually kind of poor for your use case but you should be able to get it like this:

```
$data_array = $main_array['searchResults']['nameValuePairs']['nameValuePair']
$final_array = array();
foreach($data_array as $nvp) {
    $final_array[$nvp['name']] = $nvp['value'];
}
var_dump ($final_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your edit - `['searchResults']` is not inside the `['page']` array. Try removing `['page']`.

```
foreach ($client_emails_array as $operation) 
{ 
   echo $operation['searchResults']['nameValuePairs']['nameValuePair']['name']."<br>";
   echo $operation['searchResults']['nameValuePairs']['nameValuePair']['value']."<br>";
}
```